# Xamarin: OnPropertyChanged not firing on SwipeView

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I have the following SwipeView inside a CollectionView (whose item source is an ObservableCollection):

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="transport:TransportRunningView">
        <SwipeView SwipeStarted="OnSwipeStarted">
            <SwipeView.RightItems>
                <SwipeItems Mode="Reveal">
                    <SwipeItem
                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:CurrentTransportViewModel}}, Path=AddTransportCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        IconImageSource="icon_add"
                        IsVisible="{Binding AddedToDefectTransport, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}" />
                    <SwipeItem
                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:CurrentTransportViewModel}}, Path=RemoveTransportCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        IconImageSource="icon_check"
                        IsVisible="{Binding AddedToDefectTransport}" />
                </SwipeItems>
            </SwipeView.RightItems>
...
```

The swipe items have a command that executes one of the following methods (and it is firing correctly when clicking a swipe item):

```
public ICommand AddTransportCommand { get; }
public ICommand RemoveTransportCommand { get; }

public CurrentTransportViewModel()
{
    this.AddTransportCommand = new RelayCommand<TransportRunningView>(this.AddTransport, t => !this.IsBusy);
    this.RemoveTransportCommand = new RelayCommand<TransportRunningView>(this.RemoveTransport, t => !this.IsBusy);
}

private void AddTransport(TransportRunningView transport)
{
    transport.AddedToDefectTransport = true;
    Messenger.Default.Send(transport);
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(transport.AddedToDefectTransport));
    DialogService.Toast(nameof(transport.Added));
}

private void RemoveTransport(TransportRunningView transport)
{
    transport.AddedToDefectTransport = false;
    Messenger.Default.Send(transport);
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(transport.AddedToDefectTransport));
    DialogService.Toast(Strings.Removed);
}
```

The code for the RunningTransportView class would be:

```
public partial class TransportRunningView
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TransportId { get; set; }
    public string TransportName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OriginDeparture { get; set; }
    public string OriginLocationName { get; set; }
    public string DestinationLocationName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PlannedArrival { get; set; }
    public int AdjustedTimeInMinutes { get; set; }
    public List<LocomotivesShortView> Locomotive { get; set; }

    public string DelayText => AdjustedTimeInMinutes > 0 ? $"(+{AdjustedTimeInMinutes})" : $"({AdjustedTimeInMinutes})";

    public Color DelayTextColor => AdjustedTimeInMinutes > 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
    
    public bool AddedToDefectTransport { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is that even though I call the OnPropertyChanged, it does not change the visibility of the swipe items. The desired functionality is that it would swap the swipe items on click.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: It would be better to post the full code in ViewModel . Which will be helpful to test the code directly .

Comment: why doesn't the setter for `AddedToDefectTransport` call it's own PropertyChanged?  Why do you need to do it manually?  Command and IsVisible are using different sources, so calling PropertyChanged on one wouldn't have any impact on the other.

Comment: @Jason. it does, it was just for demonstration purposes

Comment: I would think the problem is in TransportRunningView, where is the code for that?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT  added the missing code

Comment: that class does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  And I earlier asked "why doesn't the setter for AddedToDefectTransport call it's own PropertyChanged?" and you replied "it Does" when the code clearly shows that it does not